# Can anyone point me to the standards in ecma-262 that defines using parentheses for returns?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecma

```
// Create a component named MessageComponent
var MessageComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.message}</div>
    );
  }
});
```

> NOTE Why do we need the parentheses around the return statement (line
>   3)? This is because of JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion.
>   Without the parentheses, JavaScript would ignore the following lines
>   and return without a value. If the JSX starts on the same line as the
>   return, then parentheses are not needed.

Taken from [here](http://buildwithreact.com/tutorial/components).

Comment: FYI, that isn't plain Javascript so it isn't ECMA-262 that fully defines that format.  That return statement is being processed by reactjs.

Comment: If you look at the raw js that gets produced after compilation... they still use the parentheses. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#jsx-syntax

Comment: Well, if this is a JS question about Javascript standards, then post the actual JS, not the JSX.  The answer to the JS syntax is that parens are just one way to define a multiline statement.

Comment: ES5 : "*When a continue, break, return, or throw token is encountered and a LineTerminator is encountered before the next token, a semicolon is automatically inserted after the continue, break, return, or throw token.*" http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9.1 If you add the parens on the same line as this token, their is no more *LineTerminator*.

Comment: Appreciate it @Kaiido. Please put that as an answer.

Comment: ... I don't like to post a 3sec googling as an answer, Askers should search before asking...

Comment: @Kaiido have already searched for it and spent a good 10 minutes. On second thought, your answer isn't complete. I already know about the semicolon insertion. I'm looking for standard's explicit mention on the use parentheses to block semicolon insertion.

Comment: Well as I said, adding the parentheses on the same line as the token will start a new expression**, thus removing the LineTerminator. *(**Actually I didn't said that but seems obvious)*

Comment: "New expression" Yep I just realised it is just a vanilla JS parentheses closure. Great @Kaiido thanks!

Comment: Here's a good answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2846298/694086

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific part of the spec that handles using parens for returns. Parenthesis is just one way to create an expression.

Answer (score 1):

> When a continue, break, return, or throw token is encountered and a
>   LineTerminator is encountered before the next token, a semicolon is
>   automatically inserted after the continue, break, return, or throw
>   token.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/

Looks like the parentheses here are just vanilla JS expressions wrapped in parentheses i.e return (1 + 2), except multi-line:

```
function x() {
    return (
        1 + 2
    );
}
```

*Edited to not use the word closure.

Comment: Using the word [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) here can be a bit misleading.